# Android: AsyncTask causes app to crash, no error logs printed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

i am currently trying a tutorial to connect an android app with a server (link: https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/). 
However, i have difficulties with an AsyncTask which is supposed to load the elements of a database. It causes the app to crash and leaves no error logs in the logcat (also tried "no filter"). I surrounded the execute call with a try catch block as well, but the app still crashes. Any ideas what is causing the error?

here are extracts from the code:

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {
private static String url_all_products = "https://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/get_all_products.php";
... 
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
try {
            new LoadAllProducts().execute();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

...

/**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<Pair> params = new ArrayList<Pair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            AddNewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Comment: tell me one thing I can see in your code // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

please tell me what you  can see in log against json.toString() code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your code implementation. I can see webservice url in your code as

```
private static String url_all_products = "https://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/get_all_products.php";
```

The problem is with this web service. That is no longer working. I tested the webservice as you mentioned the link of the tutorial over postman, that is not working any more. Hope you get my point. Feel free to ask me if you have any confusions.

Comment: I already thought so, that this "api" is not the real deal x). But why are there no exceptions thrown or logs printed? and furthermore, how did you test the service, is it enough to setup xamp and enter the url into the browser?

Comment: yeah this is the valid question you have asked. Please check if you have applied any filter in log cat mistakenly or check your device is connected and visible in android monitor.

Comment: in this case i still should have caught some exception around the try catch block, shouldn't i? but i will try to get my hands on a server, so i can test the code with a working webserver. i appreciate your answer :)